# Find solutions $12x=3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/93\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does anybody have any idea of how to find all the solutions to
$12x=3$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{93\mathbb{Z}}$

Edit: I was able to reduce it to $4x=1 \pmod {31}$ and was able to find to $x$ using Euclid's extended algorithm. i.e. $x=8$, but I am still not able to get other 2 values that are $39$ and $70$ with some suitable method. I got these values by trying all possibilities from $0$ till $92$.

Comment: Hint: You need $3(4x-1) = 0$, so what can you conclude $4x-1$ must be divisible by?

Comment: By solving $4x$ mod 31 = 1,  I get $x=8$, but then How do I find other solutions.

Comment: Well you must have figured out that $4x-1$ needs to be divisible by $31$- but this is in fact a sufficient as well as a necessary condition to solve the original equation. So now you need to find ALL solutions of $4x \equiv 1$ (mod $31$) for $0 \leq x \leq 92$. It might help to note that $ 4 \times 8 \equiv 1$ (mod $31$), which you have already established.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  so you mean I need to traverse in the whole list from 0 till 92 one by one and try. So by trying I get 2 other solutions i.e. 39 and 70. So this is clear to me, but is there any method to solve this without trying all the values. Because I wonder if instead of 93 we have a big value then this kind of exercise becomes lengthy.  But in any case thanks for your hint.

Comment: There aren't many integers $x$ with $0 \leq x \leq 92$ and $x \equiv 8$ (mod 31).

Comment: You are right but what if instead of 93 we have big number, so still we go with trying out all possibilities or is there any method for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30964/discussion-between-techj-and-geoff-robinson).

Comment: There aren't really any shortcuts in general. If instead of $93$ we had $899 = 31 X 29$, we would have had a lot more choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$93\mid 12x- 3=3(4x-1)\iff 31\mid 4x-1$$

$$\iff 31\mid 4x-32=4(x-8)\iff 31\mid x-8$$

Therefore, all the solutions are $x\equiv \{8,39,70\}\pmod{93}$.